# Is it possible to append a component on a button press?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Here's a problem that I want to solve:
I have a button that when is pressed must append **my-component** to a dom. 
If it is pressed 2 times there must be 2 `<p>` tegs. How can I achieve this?

js:

```
<script>

  Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: "<p>hello</p>",
  })

  var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#App",
    data: {},
    methods: {
      append: function() {
         // unknown code here
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id = "App">
  <button @click="append" class="btn btn-primary">Spawn stuff!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually by having an array of data that are rendered as components, then pushing a new item to the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could do that. This code iterates over a counter using `v-for` to [iterate over a range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for).

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: "<p>hello</p>",
})

var vue = new Vue({
  el: "#App",
  data: {
    hellocount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    append: function() {
      // unknown code here
      this.hellocount++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="App">
  <my-component v-for="n in hellocount" :key="n"></my-component>

  <button @click="append" class="btn btn-primary">Spawn stuff!</button>
</div>
```

This is a little atypical; normally you will drive the components rendered from actual data, as @RoyJ suggests in your comments.

From your comment below, you could build a form something like this.

```js
Vue.component('my-input', {
  props:["value", "name"],
  data(){
    return {
      internalValue: this.value
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onInput(){
      this.$emit('input', this.internalValue)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      {{name}}:<input type="text" v-model="internalValue" @input="onInput"> 
    </div>  
    `,
})

var vue = new Vue({
  el: "#App",
  data: {
    form:{
      name: null,
      email: null,
      phone: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    append(){
      const el = prompt("What is the name of the new element?")
      this.$set(this.form, el, null)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="App">
  <my-input v-for="(value, prop) in form" 
            :key="prop" 
            v-model="form[prop]" 
            :name="prop">
  </my-input>
  
  <button @click="append">Add New Form Element</button>
  <div>
  Form Values: {{form}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The code defines a form object and iterates over the properties of the form to render inputs for each property.

This is obviously extremely naive, handles only input texts, etc. But hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I know that it may sound a little weird, but initially I wanted to figure out how to make an expendable form, so that is when a button is pressed a user would see additional input fields to add more data

Comment: @JohnAward Sure. You could define an array of input definitions and iterate over that to add input elements.

Comment: @JohnAward updated the second example as a way you might do that. Be aware it is *just* an example, doesn't cover a huge number of edge cases, etc.

Comment: I understand, it's just an example, but it's a great example considering that I'm learning vue for not that long and it provides just what I wanted to know how to do. Thank you